# Two-way ANOVA for machine learning model analysis.

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, data-analysis, anova

I have different machine learning models and losses, each trained using 5-fold cross-validation. Would it make sense to run a two-way ANOVA two evaluate which are statistically performing better? Example:

| Losses | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Loss 1 | Accuracy Fold 1, ..., Accuracy Fold 5 | ... | ... |
| Loss 2 | ... | ... | ... |
| Loss 3 | ... | ... | ... |

Would I break any assumptions by having the accuracies on different test sets (cross-validation by definition)?